# Making two-dimensional array from array in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

Its may be question from noob but, but I can't to make it...

I have array

```
arr = ["I", "wish", "I", "hadn't", "come"]
```

I need to do

```
[["I", "wish I hadn't come"], 
 ["I wish", "I hadn't come"],
 ["I wish I", "hadn't come"],
 ["I wish I hadn't", "come"]]
```

I understand how need to division that array:

```
Array.new(n) { Array[arr.shift(n).join(" "), arr.join(" ")] }
```

but `n`, I think, must change from 1 upto `(arr.size - 1)` to fill two-dimensional array with needed arrays.
How to make it I don't understand.

Comment: @Stefan Thanks. I understood, I wrongly made new arrays.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you :

```
arr = ["I", "wish", "I", "hadn't", "come"]

new_arr = (0..arr.size-2).map {|i| [arr[0..i].join(" "), arr[i+1..-1].join(" ")] }

p new_arr
```

Which outputs :

```
[
  ["I", "wish I hadn't come"], 
  ["I wish", "I hadn't come"], 
  ["I wish I", "hadn't come"], 
  ["I wish I hadn't", "come"]
]
```

Comment: Use `map` instead of `each` / `push`

Comment: Yup. You can also use `#map` to DRY-up the `#join`s: `arr.size.pred.times.map { |i| [arr[0..i], arr[(i+1)..-1]].map { |a| a.join(' ') } }`

Comment: @Pholochtairze Thanks. At last I understood mechanism. I broke my mind all week...

Comment: @Stefan : I tried a map version, is it how you thought of building it ? (I'm curious now)

Comment: Almost, you don't need `el`, so I'd write `(1..arr.size).map { |i| ... }`

Answer (score 1):

`Array#shift` is destructive, it alters your array:

```
arr = ["I", "wish", "I", "hadn't", "come"]

[arr.shift(2).join(" "), arr.join(" ")]
#=> ["I wish", "I hadn't come"]

arr
#=> ["I", "hadn't", "come"]
```

You can use [`Array#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D) instead:

```
arr = ["I", "wish", "I", "hadn't", "come"]

arr[0..2]
#=> ["I", "wish", "I"]

arr[3..-1]
#=> ["hadn't", "come"]
```

`-1` refers to the last element.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using [slice](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-slice), which can return a select part of the array, rather than [shift](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-shift), which can achieve the same thing for the first n elements but modifies the original array in doing so. Combining this with your idea of looping from 1 to size-1 will help you reach your goal. The `for i in 1..n do` syntax is one way of doing this.

Comment: `for` loops are rarely used nowadays.

Comment: Good point. I thought the 1..n-1 syntax would help as the OP seems to understand the start and end indices he wants to use, but this would be a good opportunity to look into what else Ruby has to offer, e.g. [times](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Integer.html#method-i-times), or for this case [map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map), as you suggested.

Comment: I had idea with loops and maybe I finded right decision, but I forgot required new array in the end

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do this:

```
require "pp"

arr = ["I", "wish", "I", "hadn't", "come"]

r = (1...arr.size).collect  {|i| [arr.take(i).join(" "), arr.drop(i).join(" ")]}

pp r
#=> [["I", "wish I hadn't come"],
#   ["I wish", "I hadn't come"],
#   ["I wish I", "hadn't come"],
#   ["I wish I hadn't", "come"]]
```